# Como ocultar title quado radio é selecionado?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero colocar uma lista de artigos em meu site e quero que tenha o nome e uma pequena descrição de cada artigo ao lado de um radio. Quando o radio  pertencente a um artigo é clicado, surge uma descrição do artigo. Isto já está funcionando.

Mas eu quero usar um texto descritivo nos radios para que quando o ponteiro do mouse passar sobre cada um, surja a instrução dizendo algo como “Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo.”.
Em cada radio, eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="radio" title= "Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." />
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de que, quando um radio estiver clicado, este não exiba mais a mensagem em title, caso o ponteiro do mouse passe sobre ele. Ou seja: eu gostaria de que quanto o radio for clicado, a atributo title seja retirado do radio em questão. Quando outro radio for clicado o mesmo que descrevo acima deve acontecer com ele e o que havia sido clicado anteriormente, deve receber o atributo title de volta.

Eu estou começando a usar Jquery e não consigo fazer muita coisa. Até o memento o mais próximo que consegui fazer foi isto aqui abaixo - mas não está funcionado como esperado - baseado no exemplo que [encontrei](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" title="Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." name="tl-group" /> Artigo 1
<br>
<input type="radio" title="Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." name="tl-group" /> Artigo 2
<br>
<input type="radio" title="Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." name="tl-group" /> Artigo 3
<br>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  var ConteudoTitle = $("input").attr("title");
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var input = $(this);

    if (input.attr("title") === ConteudoTitle) {
      input.removeAttr("title")
    } else {
      input.attr("title", ConteudoTitle);
    }    
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução simples seria utilizando o próprio `.attr`, defini uma classe para que seja alterado somente os radio que queremos:

```
/*Pego o evento de alteração nos seus radios*/
$('.radioArtigo').change(function() {
  /*seto a mensagem para todos*/ 
  $('.radioArtigo').attr('title', 'Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo.'); 
  /*Removo a mensagem do selecionado*/
  $(this).attr('title', '');  
});
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/pq84yusm/).

Comment: Obrigado @Brunno. Usando sua sugestão deu certo após adicionar "title= "Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." na tag imput, pois, eu quero que a mensagem apareça antes de qualquer radio ser selecionado, visto que todos devem ser carregados sem seleção. Ficou assim: <input type="radio" class="radioArtigo" name="tl-group"title= "Clique aqui para ver o resumo do artigo." />. Mas como eu tenho outro script que mostra um tootip similar a este: [link] (http://designreflect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/jquery-tooltip-plugins/Responsive-Tooltip.jpg), estou enfrentando um problema de conflito...

Comment: @Raniere, se você adicionar a class somente nos radios que você está utilizando ele não casará problemas nos outros.

Comment: Então, creio que é exatamente isso que fiz. Mas mesmo assim estou com um problema de conflito com outro script  que tenho, responsável por gerar o efeito de toottip nos titles como mostra a imagem no link acima. Digo isso porque se removo um script, o outro funciona, e vice-versa.
Neste tooltip que estou usando uso JQuery-ui, então, deve haver conflito entre JQuery e JQuery-ui.
Soluções como descrito aqui: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/13871/jquery/evitando-conflitos-com-jquerynoconflict/
não surtiram efeito. Estou tentando implementar um script para o tooltip com JQuery e ver se resolve.

Comment: @Raniere, fiz um exemplo de cada para você nesse [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/pq84yusm/2/), tem um exemplo com UI e o evento de não mostrar se selecionado, um exemplo do UI e o jQuery funcionando juntos. Acho que seu problema está sento ao chamar o tooltip do UI, você deve está apendado ele ao  $( document ).tooltip(); ai ele vai causar conflitos mesmo. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Eu agradeço seu empenho @Brunno, mas não estou conseguindo usar este eu último exemplo fora do fiddle. Parece também haver um comportamento "anormal" na seção "jQuery-UI com a logica de não mostrar se selecionado". Este seu parece não mostrar mais o tootip após ele ter sido selecionado, isso é bem o que eu queria mesmo, mas, quando desselecionado o radio, o tootip deveria voltar a ser exibido. Isso não ocorre aqui.

Comment: @Raniere, não tinha observado isto hehehe, fiz outro [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/pq84yusm/4/) só com o jQuery ui com isso corrigido e com a lógica um pouco diferente. :)

Comment: Olá @Brunno.
Estou usando em meu projeto este script para gerar o tootip:
http://jsfiddle.net/b8fcg/1/
A ideia é que ele seja gerado em todos os locais onde tenha uma title e está funcionando como esperado.
Eu consigo usar o seu código jundo deste acima em meu projeto, mas não consigo colocar um arrow em seu código. Você poderia me indicar uma forma de juntar o seu código a este em cima a fim de colocar um arrow no tooltip criado pelo seu código?